# disable vim unfolding blocks of text when one of its embedded words is matched

Tags: folding

While navigating between search pattern matches , if one of the matches happened to be embedded within a block of text , the whole block gets unfolded .

Is there a way to substitute this behavior with one that highlights the one-liner folded text or effortlessly just stop at it during navigation ?

Comment: You could probably write a custom `n`/`N` map that (1) uses `search()` to get the position of the next match and (2) uses `foldclosed()`/`foldclosedend()` to check on the folds. Then you could do whatever it is you want regarding jumping to a match or the fold or whatever, making sure to respect `'wrapscan'`. But note that if you jump to the beginning of a fold containing a match, the next match will always be the one in the fold… so if you want to later "skip" over it, you need to handle that case.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I currently only know the bare common knowledge about vim . With such implementation involving logical conditionals and exceptions , i don't think i'm up to implement it . Nonetheless i did grasp the abstract concept itself .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `:help 'foldopen'`:

```
                        *'foldopen'* *'fdo'*
'foldopen' 'fdo'    string (default: "block,hor,mark,percent,quickfix,
                                 search,tag,undo")
            global
            {not available when compiled without the +folding
            feature}
    Specifies for which type of commands folds will be opened, if the
    command moves the cursor into a closed fold.  It is a comma separated
    list of items.
    NOTE: When the command is part of a mapping this option is not used.
    Add the zv command to the mapping to get the same effect.
    (rationale: the mapping may want to control opening folds itself)
```

So you can remove the 'search' from the default in your .vimrc:

```
set foldopen-=search
```

Comment: Thanks . That met the second case of stopping at the encompassing fold .

Comment: @D.BenKnoble indeed , it made the exclusion more distinguishable .

Comment: @D.BenKnoble agreed and updated